# My Programm does not count correctly Inversions in MergeSort Array

Tags: java, mergesort

Below is the code I have written on Java to read the 100000 integers from a text file and to sort them using merge sort.

Issues:

The program does not correctly count Inversions and I don't know where is the problem?

I test my code on this array long[] arrayB = {4, 3, 2, 1,  8, 7, 5, 3, 6 }. It shows 20 inversions against 15 .

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Nick\\Desktop\\ArrayInt.txt"));
    long[] arrayA = new long[100_000];
    int i = 0;
    while (reader.readLine() != (null)) {
        arrayA[i] = Long.parseLong(reader.readLine());
        i++;
    }
    reader.close();
    long[] arrayB = {4, 3, 2, 1,  8, 7, 5, 3, 6 };
    long invb = getMergeSort(arrayB);
    long testInvB = simpleInvCount(arrayB);
    System.out.println(invb);
    System.out.println(testInvB);
    System.out.println( (float) testInvB / invb);

}
public static long simpleInvCount(long [] A){
    long invCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            if (A[i] < A[j])
                invCount++;
        }
    }
    return invCount;
}
```

// Получим от сортированный массив методом Слияния

```
public static long getMergeSort(long[] A) {
    long invCount = 0;
    if (A.length == 0 || A.length == 1) return 0;
    else {
        int mid = A.length / 2 ;
        long[] left = Arrays.copyOfRange( A, 0, mid); // Левая часть массива
        long[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange( A, mid, A.length); // Правая часть массива
         invCount += getMergeSort(left);
         invCount += getMergeSort(right);

             invCount += toMerge(left,right);
        return invCount;

    }

}

public static long toMerge(long [] left, long [] right){
    long [] temp = new long [left.length + right.length];
    int i = 0, // индекс массива С
    j = 0, // индекс массива Д
    k=0, // индекс итогового массива temp
    invCount = 0; // количество перестановок

    while (i < left.length && j < right.length){
        if (left[i] < right[j]){
            temp[k++] = left[i++];
        } else
            temp[k++] = right[j++];
            invCount = invCount + (left.length - i);
    }

    while (i < left.length){
        temp[k++] = left[i++];
    }

    while (j < right.length){
        temp[k++] = right[j++];
    }

    return invCount;
}
```

}

On this array long[] arrayB = {4, 3, 2, 1,  8, 7, 5, 3, 6 } I expect the output will be 15, but actual output is 20.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ This program should be very easy to debug, since for each subarray you should know how many inversions it has. Also, I'm sure your test can be minimized. And in competitive programming, which you seem to be doing, ability to debug is a must.

Comment: Thank you. I'm a newbie in programming. Yes u are right my test was minimized because I don't know how to debug. I have not debugged any program yet. So I will try.